# GAL 16v8 tri-state independent pin control

Tags: fpga, vhdl, logic-gates, multiplexer, programmable-logic

I would like to use GAL chips for a project.
16V8, 22V10, 26V12.

I have read that the tri-state status of a pin maybe controlled individually.

I do not understand how write the equations to individually control the Hi-Z per pin feature, or tell the compiler that is what I have in mind.

- This is where I am asking for help & direction.
  Many tutorials discuss it can be done, but I haven't found one that illustrates direct control of Hi-Z per pin..

Directly:

How can I use pins (as shown) as an input, to control separately the Hi-Z status of any two or more output pins.

---

I am using OPAL-Jr for all I've needed before.

data sheet:

http://www.latticesemi.com/Search.aspx?&lcid=9&q=gal16v8&t=480

This is what I am looking to learn, but cannot find as clear as this.
[image]

"Each output normally uses a single product term to enable it, so program it like any other signal. – Finbarr"

That is what I don't know.
How to write equations that address individual OE's, not just as a group OE.

Comment: Each output normally uses a single product term to enable it, so program it like any other  signal.

Comment: The real question would be… they do still make GALs? even CPLDs these days are simply low density FPGAs in disguise. Usually you write a separate equation for the OE term of each output to use the tristate features.

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio Yep, Microchip is still producing GALs.

Comment: Magic_Smoke - Hi, Thanks for being polite and saying thank you, but on this site, that shouldn't be posted as an *answer* in the box labeled "Your Answer" which you used. Instead, please read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) & [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), consider "upvoting" all helpful answers (although as a new user, your votes may not be visible) and consider "accepting" the most useful of the given answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GAL16V8                ; this is the second example
Exa.2

A  B  C  D  E  F  G  NC NC GND
NC NC NC NC NC NC Y3 Y2 Y1 VCC
...

Y3.T = /G
Y3.E = E * F    

DESCRIPTION

 tristate output:  pinname.T
 tristate control: pinname.E
```

-- https://github.com/daveho/GALasm/blob/master/examples/Tristate.pld

from the documentation for [GALasm](https://github.com/daveho/GALasm),
which seems to be a popular ( [a](https://justanotherelectronicsblog.com/?p=458) [b](https://hackaday.com/tag/galasm/) [c](https://edf.bu.edu/trac/edf/wiki/GalBlaster) ) equation-to-GAL-fusemap assembler.

OPAL-Jr may use a different syntax than GALasm (Thanks, Bruce Abbot!), but you're not going to find that syntax in the GAL datasheets, but in the OPAL-Jr documentation.

Answer (score 1):

> I am using OPAL-Jr

In Opaljr an output pin's tristate or 'OE' (Output Enable) function is specified by appending `.oe` to the output name. So in your example the equation would be eg.

```
l8.oe = l12
```

Most GALs have three different global modes - Simple, Complex, and Registered. In Simple mode outputs are permanently enabled or disabled, so `.oe` cannot be used. However if you apply `.oe` to a combinatorial output the compiler should automatically choose an appropriate mode (complex or registered) that supports it. In the GAL16V8 pin 11 is a shared OE which is permanently assigned to all registered outputs, so you cannot control them individually.